# Redirect urls in all wordpress posts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website in wordpress and I need to redirect specific urls, I think it can be done with the .htaccess or through php code or javascript.
Pay attention:
My site creates listings that are like post as follows:
https://agents.nzschoolinfo.com/school/remuera-intermediate-school/
I need all urls to be redirected like this:
https://nzschoolinfo.com/ko-kr/school/remuera-intermediate-school/

Just to be clear.

My site creates with this url:

https://agents.nzschoolinfo.com/school/EXAMPLE1.

https://agents.nzschoolinfo.com/school/EXAMPLE2.

https://agents.nzschoolinfo.com/school/EXAMPLE3

I need to redirect that to this:

https://nzschoolinfo.com/ko-kr/school/EXAMPLE1.

https://nzschoolinfo.com/ko-kr/school/EXAMPLE2.

https://nzschoolinfo.com/ko-kr/school/EXAMPLE3.

I don't really know why it uses a subdomain to create this. But I need to redirect it to the main domain.
I would appreciate very much who could help me.
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a code which generates those links?

Comment: I do not have access to the code, there is no way to redirect without it?

Comment: So try to check Wordpress admin dashboard->Settings->General->WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's weird but they're fine, in fact the whole site is fine. Like the posts and other things, only the listings plugin generates with the wrong url, I think it is a plugin problem